Where should user-editable configuration file go?
I want to store my app configuration in a JSON file, that user can edit. Where can I place it to avoid requesting full storage access permission? I'm targeting Android 11 and higher.

One option is to use ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT to let the user decide where to put the JSON. When you get the Uri back, you can call takePersistableUriPermissions() on ContentResolver to have long-term access to the content identified by the Uri. You can also use ContentResolver and its openInputStream() and openOutputStream() methods to read and write the JSON with your favorite JSON parser.
Another option is to store the JSON in the Documents/ or Downloads/ directories using ordinary file I/O. You have the ability to write files there, plus the ability to read files that you wrote.

Thanks for the anwer, it looks like Documents folder is the way to go, I have a problem with permissions though. I get documents folder path with Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS). I request media permissions (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), however app crashes with EEXIST (File exists) when creating a file and with EACCES (Permission denied) when reading. I can see in device settings that media permissions are actually granted but the app works only if I manually give it "manage all files". What am I doing wrong?

@michuu: Make sure you are creating new files. Your app does not have read or write access to files in Documents/ created by other apps.
